# Installing Pandas in pyCharm giving error Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, runtime-error

I am trying to install pandas in pyCharm, however I am continuously receiving the following error message:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279
```

Now I have already downloaded and installed Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0  through the link they provided me however I'm still represented with the same error. I even tried installing it from the terminal of pyCharm which gives out the following:

```
(python.exe) C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python>pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2018.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.12.0)
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I also tried upgrading pip however this is what's being displayed:

```
(python.exe) C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\python.exe\lib\site-packages (18.1)
```

I rebooted the PC multiple times.

```
(python.exe) C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python>SET
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
SESSIONNAME=Console
COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-0OV717O
TMP=C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
OneDriveConsumer=C:\Users\danie\OneDrive
__INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE__=C:\Users\danie\.PyCharm2018.3\config\terminal\history\history-
SystemDrive=C:
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-0OV717O
TEMP=C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
HOMEPATH=\Users\danie
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT=$P$G
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C
:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\
Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\P
rogram Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;D:\Program Files\JRE\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\
NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;D:\Program Files\Python3;C:\Users\danie\App
Data\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts;
USERNAME=danie
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DESKTOP-0OV717O
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local
TERMINAL_EMULATOR=JetBrains-JediTerm
VIRTUAL_ENV=C:\Miniconda3\envs\my_env\python.exe
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
APPDATA=C:\Users\danie\AppData\Roaming
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-0OV717O
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
GOOGLE_API_KEY=no
PROCESSOR_REVISION=9e09
OneDrive=C:\Users\danie\OneDrive
GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID=no
PROJECT_DIR=C:/Users/danie/Desktop/Python
PATH=C:\Miniconda3\envs\my_env\python.exe\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\
Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\
OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Manag
ement Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;D:\Program Files\JRE\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\W
irelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;D:\Program
Files\Python3;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts;
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\danie
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
windir=C:\WINDOWS
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
OS=Windows_NT
asl.log=Destination=file
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
PROMPT=(python.exe) $P$G
HOMEDRIVE=C:
GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET=no
```

Comment: Did you restart your pc? without it it won't work (probably)

Comment: Yes I did ... ''And yes I rebooted the PC multiple times''

Comment: Check if you have something along the lines of "Command Prompt for VS ..." in start menu. Make sure built tools installed correctly (one of the subfolders of Microsoft Visual Studio in Program Files), probably Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools in Program Files folder

Comment: @Shan Yea I have that ''Command Prompt for VS'' What do you mean by build tools installed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're running Anaconda environment and yet attempt to install modules via pip. It's a bad practice, especially on Windows. Anaconda provides also binary, non-Python dependencies for your environment.

Correct approach:

1. Activate your virtual environment
2. Install pandas: `conda install pandas`

That being said, your way, although not recommended, should also work. To troubleshoot, run in command line:

1. `vcvarsall.bat` and present the output.
2. `SET`. This will give us all environment variables.

*[EDIT - aftermath]*

Install modules via Anaconda Command Prompt, not PyCharm. PyCharm won't load environmental variables that are needed to build packages.

Comment: I tried doing both on what you recommended and this is what was outputted: 
`(python.exe) C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python> vcvarsall.bat
'vcvarsall.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

`(python.exe) C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python>conda install pandas
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @DavidVella Can you start Anaconda console? It should be under your start menu.

Comment: Well through anacondas terminal it does install however not through pyCharm

Comment: @DavidVella Your PyCharm should point to your virtualenv, set correct interpreter in the IDE. Still, I'd not try to install anything via PyCharm. It won't set environment variables, as demonstrated by your example. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested and successfully downloaded everything from anaconda however when opening and loading the environment on pycharm now Im getting this error `ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy. Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Process finished with exit code 1` P.S The numpy installed is the latest

Comment: Have you created a new environment in Anaconda (`conda create -n yourname`)? https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe should have numpy in the package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (missing Visual C++...) when i try to run my python program using pandas. I have successfully used conmand line : pip  install pandas, but still got error. Restart computer cannot resolve this problem.
So i decided to give up this IDE, PyCharm. Instead i installed the IDE "Visual Studio Code", then the error dispeared.